# FBGraph on facebook fan page with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook

I have many doubts with fbgraph ruby gem. I understand if my page is a independent application which can connect to Facebook.

Now I don´t understand how I should take the user information if my page is on Facebook fan page. I know what Facebook send me `params['signed_request']`.

However I don't understand how and when I should use `fbgraph ruby wrapper` if my site is on Facebook fan page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add a filter in my application controller.

```
def parse_facebook
 @auth = FbGraph::Auth.new(configatron.fb_authentication_app_key, configatron.fb_authentication_app_secret).from_signed_request params[:signed_request]
end
```

This could be modified for other scenarios however this is the simplest example.